# Redirect root of the subfolder but not the folders under that with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a Modx site with multiple languages.
I am trying to do a redirect for the url

```
https://example.com/fi/
```

to

https://example.com/fi/something

But I only want to redirect the root of the "subfolder" not anything under that eg. "example.com/fi/products" or anything else. Just the root /fi/

The current htaccess file is as follows

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteBase /

#Check for Fi
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fi [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/fi/ [L,R=301]

# Default to En
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/en/ [L,R=301]

# Fix current links

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/en
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/fi
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [L]

# The Friendly URLs part
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If I try to

```
RedirectMatch 301 /fi /fi/something
```

I end up with endless loop of /fi/something in the URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rewrite loop exists because your target URL `/fi/something` obviously again is matched by your pattern `/fi` ...

Actually you don't want to use `RedirectMatch` here at all, but a simple `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^/?fi/?$ /fi/something [R=301,L]
```

You want to add that rule to the existing configuration file above the comment `# Fix current links`.